# What does Control+Shift+[click on taskbar item] in Windows 7 do?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, uac

When I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on an item in the taskbar in Windows 7, a UAC dialogue pops up asking if I want to allow the program to make changes to my system.

I daren't grant permission lest it uninstall the program or something (though it seems unlikely since I get the same message when I do in on an Explorer window), but I can't find any reference to the shortcut.

What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This merely runs the clicked program as an administrator.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

Under "Taskbar Keyboard Shortcuts"

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't understand very well the UAC dialogues and what this whole feature is, read this article: [What is UAC & Why You Should Never Turn it Off](http://www.7tutorials.com/uac-why-you-should-never-turn-it-off)

It explains everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was just about the function of the key combo, not the UAC window.